# Generics extend without extend - how to do

Tags: java, extends, redundancy

I've done some stuff:

```
class Tuple1<T1, T2> {
    private T1 a;
    private T2 b;

    public Tuple1(T1 a, T2 b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public T1 getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public T2 getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + a.toString() + ", " + b.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Now I must to do Tuple2 (a, b + c field) and Tuple3 (a, b, c + d field), which will have the same functions as Tuple1, but without `extends` and without code redundancy.

Comment: Interesting home work. Any ideas yet how to solve it?

Comment: Your current usage does not have extends either. And what do you mean by code redundancy - to reuse Tuple1 in Tuple2's construction?

Comment: You could take a look at the source code of the jOOλ library, which implements something very much like what you're trying to do: http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.12/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider following solution:

```
class Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    private T1 a;
    private T2 b;

    public Tuple1(T1 a, T2 b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public T1 getA() { return a; }

    public T2 getB() { return b; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + a.toString() + ", " + b.toString() + "]";
    }
}

class Tuple2<T1, T2, T3> 
{
    private Tuple1<T1, T2> tuple;
    private T3 c;

    public Tuple2(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c)
    {
        this.tuple = new Tuple1<T1, T2>(a, b);
        this.c = c;
    }

    public T1 getA() { return tuple.getA(); }

    public T2 getB() { return tuple.getB(); }

    public T3 getC() { return c; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + getA().toString() + ", " + getB().toString() + ", " + c.toString() + "]";
    }
}

class Tuple3<T1, T2, T3, T4> 
{
    private Tuple2<T1, T2, T3> tuple;
    private T4 d;

    public Tuple3(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c, T4 d)
    {
        this.tuple = new Tuple2<T1, T2, T3>(a, b, c);
        this.d = d;
    }

    public T1 getA() { return tuple.getA(); }

    public T2 getB() { return tuple.getB(); }

    public T3 getC() { return tuple.getC(); }

    public T4 getD() { return d; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + getA().toString() + ", " + getB().toString() + ", " + getC().toString() + ", " + d.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple constructor which can do do what you want :

for example :

```
private T1 a;
private T2 b;
//create a new attribute
private T2 c;

//constructor with two attributes
public Tuple1(T1 a, T2 b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

//constructor with three attributes
public Tuple1(T1 a, T2 b, T2 c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

//getters and setters of your attributes
```

So when you want to use two attribute :

```
Tuple1 t1 = new Tuple1(a, b);
```

So when you want to use three attribute :

```
Tuple1 t2 = new Tuple1(a, b, c);
```

You can learn more in this Oracle tutorial: [Getting Started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

and about [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but Tuple2 and Tuple3 must be a class.

Comment: @hqid, yes then you can create classes with different constructor like i do before

Answer (score 1):

You could make `Tuple2<T1, T2, T3>` and similar for Tuple3. You would store `Tuple1<T1, T2>` as a private field inside Tuple2 alongside `T3 c`, and implement all required methods, with some of them just delegating their calls to appropriate Tuple1 methods. It might seem like it's redundant, but you do need to have a method declared in order to call it, so there's no way to avoid that.